# Set Hydra default config in the decorator

Tags: hydra, fb-hydra

Is there a way to define **the default config in the hydra decorator** and w/o saving it to any yaml file? For some small scripts it might be very hande.

Something like this:

```
@hydra.main(default={var1='default_value1', var2='xxx'}) 
def main(cfg):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define "the default config in the hydra decorator" in the way you presented it.

However, but take a look at the [Structured Configs tutorial](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/intro).
The first page there is similar in spirit to what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: @Temak, If this answers your question - can you accept the answer?